# How to access to a file in docker container already exit?

Tags: docker

I create a file hello.txt:

```
docker run centos6-ssh echo "hello world" > /root/hello.txt
```

docker will create a container,excecute the command,and the container exit.
probblem is that how do i access the file?

in case of container exit,the right way to use container is run a container with ssh service background(-d args)?

Answer (score 30):

The right way is to just use the `docker cp` command. After your container exited you can get it's id by doing `docker ps -a`. Note the id of the container then do:

```
docker cp <container_id>:/root/hello.txt .
```

Comment: still doesn't work:`[root@localhost ~]# docker cp 725f84fdb23f:/root/hello.txt /root/
2014/05/10 20:53:25 Tarball too short`,why docker close container?can it just open like a virtual machine?

Comment: A container is just a collection of resources under its own namespace.  These resources include the filesystem, network ports, and a process tree. So long as the container exists (has a valid docker id), its technically "open". This is why you can use the `docker cp` command to access the disk after the process has stopped. If you want your docker container to behave like a vm it needs to run processes such as `sshd`.

Comment: thanks!is it suitable if i run ssh service in every container?

Comment: Its technically possible, but depends on your use case and is probably outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 6):

```
docker container ls -a
```

to list starting and exited containers, and select a $containerId,

then

```
docker container export -o myContainerFileSystem.tar $containerId
```

to extract the filesystem as tar file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy (a git-like commit) of the container as a new image then run a command using that image in a new container.

e.g.

```bash
> # List all containers, including exited ones (-a)
> docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                          PORTS     NAMES
a01f3b347982   66957874a804   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/bi…"   9 minutes ago   Exited (1) About a minute ago             elegant_ganguly

> # Create an image based on the selected 'Container ID'
> docker container commit a01f3b347982 container_exit_1234

> # Create an interractive bash shell in a terminal (-ti) in that image
> docker run -ti --entrypoint=bash container_exit_1234
>$
>$ cd /root
>$ cat hello.txt
hello_world
>$ exit

> # Alternately run that container in the background (-id) and send it commands using 'exec'
> docker run -id --entrypoint=bash --name run1234.1 container_exit_1234
> docker exec run1234.1 cat /root/hello.txt
hello world
> docker kill run1234.1

> # This can be done multiple times with the same image
> docker run -id --entrypoint=bash --name run1234.2 container_exit_1234
> docker exec run1234.2 rm /root/hello.txt
> docker kill run1234.2

> # Remember as this is a container, the base image remains unchanged
> docker run -id --entrypoint=bash --name run1234.3 container_exit_1234
> docker exec run1234.3 test -f /root/hello.txt && echo "PHEW!!"
PHEW!!
> docker kill run1234.3
```

Answer (score -4):

i think the right way to use container is run a container with ssh service background(-d args)